# Microsoft Remote Desktop (Android) To Windows 8 Pro

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1, android

I try to access my Windows 8 PC from my Android device using the official app *Microsoft Remote Desktop*, and it is not working. 
The error message is: *Connection Error - Unable to connect to remote PC. Please verify Remote Desktop is enabled, the remote PC is turned on and available on the network, and then try again.*

I did the following things so far:

On Windows 8 PC:

- Set up just one user, which is linked to my Microsoft ID.
- Allowed incoming remote connections:
  [image]
  .

On Router:

- Routed port 3389 to the same port of my Windows 8 PC
- Set up a static IP for my Windows 8 PC

On Android App:

- Set up *PC name* parameter to IP of Windows 8 PC (and also tried the name of the Windows 8 PC)
- Entered my Windows Live ID as user
- Entered the respective password

Comment: It's safe to assume you have linked your username to a Microsoft account?

Comment: Yes, I did so right before. And it is shown as having access on remote desktop users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your combining a few things. If you are using port forwarding, you shouldn't be putting in your PC name or IP, you should be using your external IP.

### On your internal network

Make sure your phone is on your home wifi network. Try to use the RDP app by putting in the IP of your desktop. If doesn't work then it shouldn't have anything to do with your router, it has to do with your configuration.

### From the outside

Now turn off your phone's wifi. Put in your external IP address. If this doesn't work but the it does work on the wifi, your port forwarding isn't set up correctly.

Comment: Ok, I removed the port forwarding, since I do not want to access the PC from outside of my network. My phone is on my wifi network, surfing the web works with it (no SIM card inserted). Providing the IP does not work, I get the same error.

Comment: Is your firewall on on the PC? Also, try using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping&hl=en) to ping your computer from Android

Comment: I am so stupid. :) That's it, thank you very much.